# Grouping list items by modulo?

Tags: python

I created a list that includes 14 integers. I wanted to group them by modulo. I can group them but I dont want to duplicate numbers in same group.

for ex:

```
[13, 40, 42, 17, 43, 45, 45, 6, 7, 7, 46, 48, 22, 51]
```

output:

```
[[13], [40], [42], [17, 43], [45, 45, 6], [7, 7, 46], [48, 22], [51]]
```

but it should be:

```
[[13], [40], [42], [17, 43],[45],[45, 6],[7],[ 7, 46], [48, 22], [51]]
```

my code

```
def projection(val):
    return val %13 

player1_sorted = sorted(player1,key=projection)
print(player1_sorted)
player1_grouped = [list(it) for k, it in groupby(player1_sorted, projection)]
```

Comment: But you want to maintain the order?

Comment: What if you have `[45, 45, 45, 6]`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't have 3 same value in list.Yes I want to maintain order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to split the sub lists:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

def chunker(it):
    chunk = []
    for x in it:
        if chunk and x == chunk[-1]:
            yield chunk
            chunk = []
        chunk.append(x)
    if chunk:
        yield chunk


[*chain(*([*chunker(g)] for _, g in groupby(player1, key=projection)))]
# [[13], [40], [42], [17, 43], [45], [45, 6], [7], [7, 46], [48, 22], [51]]
```